# Blazor (Server Side) and Okta

Tags: blazor, okta, blazor-server-side

I am currently going through this post to integrate okta into a Blazor Server Side App

https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/10/16/csharp-blazor-authentication

I am currently getting “Sorry, there's nothing at this address”.

I was hoping someone could provide a suggestion to my problem.

**Or does anyone know of an example to integrate okta into a Blazor Server Side App?**

Please let me know.

Any help would be appreciated. I am totally spinning my wheels.

**Here are my okta General Settings:**

[image]
Below is code from my solution (I reviewed the post so many times to make sure it is right. But I guess I could of missed something.)

**StartUp ConfigureServices**

```
       services.AddAuthorizationCore();
        services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
            {
                sharedOptions.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                sharedOptions.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddCookie()
            .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
            {
                options.ClientId = Configuration["Okta:ClientId"];
                options.ClientSecret = Configuration["Okta:ClientSecret"];
                options.Authority = Configuration["Okta:Issuer"];
                options.CallbackPath = "/authorization-code/callback";
                options.ResponseType = "code";
                options.SaveTokens = true;
                options.UseTokenLifetime = false;
                options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
                options.Scope.Add("openid");
                options.Scope.Add("profile");
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    NameClaimType = "name"
                };
            });
    }
```

**StartUp Configure**

```
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
            endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
        });
    }
```

**MainLayout.razor**

```
<div class="top-row px-4">

    <AuthorizeView>
        <Authorized>
            <a href="Identity/Account/Manage">Hello, @context.User.Identity.Name!</a>
            <a href="Identity/Account/LogOut">Log out</a>
        </Authorized>
        <NotAuthorized>
            <a href="Identity/Account/Register">Register</a>
            <a href="Identity/Account/Login">Log in</a>
        </NotAuthorized>
    </AuthorizeView>

    <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/" target="_blank">About</a>
</div>
```

**App.razor**

````
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState> ```
````

Comment: Can you do this: At the top of the App component add: @inject NavigationManager NavigationManager In the <NotFound><LayoutView> element place this: @{
                           var returnUrl = NavigationManager.ToBaseRelativePath(NavigationManager.Uri); Console.WriteLine(returnUrl); }  Please report what value is printed

Comment: The value I am getting is: "Identity/Account/Login"

Comment: Start with this options.CallbackPath = "/authorization-code/callback"; You've posted here an image of a file. Where in the world this file reside ? Anyhow, see if you can and should alter the call back related to there. It should be provided with existing url. Good luck , and report

Comment: OK, I will give it, it might take a little bit, but I will let you know.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you click on the "Log in" anchor element, the "Identity/Account/Login" path cannot be found by the Router, the result of which is displaying

Sorry, there's nothing at this address.

.Of course you are not directed to the okta web site, and no authentication takes place, right ?

It is beyond me to understand why she set up the AuthorizeView component like this. It seems to me, though, that her whole article was designed by a municipal committee, and assembled from spare code snippets. However, this is beyond the scope of this answer.

### Solution

1. Create a component named LoginDisplay (LoginDisplay.razor), and place it in the Shared folder. This component is used in the MainLayout component

   `<AuthorizeView>
       <Authorized>
           <a href="logout">Hello, @context.User.Identity.Name!</a>
           <form method="get" action="logout">
               <button type="submit" class="nav-link btn btn-link">Log out</button>
           </form>
       </Authorized>
       <NotAuthorized>
          <a href="login?redirectUri=/">Log in</a>
       </NotAuthorized>
   </AuthorizeView>`

   Add the LoginDisplay component to the MainLayout component, just above the About
   anchor element, like this

   `<div class="top-row px-4">
       <LoginDisplay />
       <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/" target="_blank">About</a>
   </div>`

Note: In order to redirect requests for login and for logout to okta, we have to create two Razor pages as follows:
1. Create a Login Razor page Login.cshtml (Login.cshtml.cs) and place them in the Pages folder as follow:

### Login.cshtml.cs

```
 using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
 using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
 using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
 using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;

public class LoginModel : PageModel
{
    public async Task OnGet(string redirectUri)
    {
        await 
    HttpContext.ChallengeAsync(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, 
    new AuthenticationProperties
    {
            RedirectUri = redirectUri
    });
  }
}
```

This code starts the challenge for the Open Id Connect authentication scheme you defined in the Startup class.

2. Create a Logout Razor page Logout.cshtml (Logout.cshtml.cs) and place them in the Pages folder as well:

   ### Logout.cshtml.cs

`using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;`

 `public class LogoutModel : PageModel
 {
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
    {
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync();
        return Redirect("/");
    }
 }`

This code sign you out, redirecting you to the Home page of your Blazor app.

Replace the code in App.razor with the following code:

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>

<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" 
      DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <NotAuthorized>

                  @*<RedirectToLogin />*@
            </NotAuthorized>
            <Authorizing>
                Wait...
            </Authorizing>
        </AuthorizeRouteView>
    </Found>
    <NotFound>

            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
            </LayoutView>

    </NotFound>

 </Router>
 </CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

Run your app, click on the log in button to authenticate

Note: I've not finished my answer...I've more to add, but I can't do it now. I'll do it as soon as I can. If you have questions, please don't hesitate to ask. I'll answer them, if I can...;)

Note: This sample works for me great.

Please don't forget your appsettings.json file. It should be something like this:

```
{
  "Okta": {
    "Issuer": "https://dev-621531.okta.com/oauth2/default",
    "ClientId": "0o1a5bsivg6wFDw6Jr347",
    "ClientSecret": "ffolkG3sd2NgQ_E909etXRU3cXX3wBpgE0XxcmF5"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Don't try to use my settings, as I've changed them...
The code in the Startup class is correct, but you may need to add some namespace references, perhaps nuget packages which I added,etc.

Note: While you're experimenting with your app, you should clear the browsing data, if you want to be redirected to okta's login page, otherwise, your browser may use the cached data.

**Update**
Note that creating a login mechanism as is done here does not make your app more secured than before. Any user can access your web resources without needing to log in at all. In order to secure parts of your web site, you have to implement authorization as well, conventionally, an authenticated user is authorized to access secured resource, unless other measures are implemented, such as roles, policies, etc. The following is a demonstration how you can secured your Fetchdata page from unauthorized users (again, authenticated user is considered authorized to access the Fetchdata page).

1. At the top of the Fetchdata component page add the @attribute directive for the Authorize attribute, like this: `@attribute [Authorize]`
   When an unauthenticated user tries to access the Fetchdata page, the `AuthorizeRouteView.NotAuthorized` delegate property is executed, so we can add some code to redirect the user to the same okta's login page to authenticate.
2. place this code within the NotAuthorized element, like this:

   `<NotAuthorized>
       @{
           var returnUrl = 
           NavigationManager.ToBaseRelativePath(NavigationManager.Uri);
           NavigationManager.NavigateTo($"login?redirectUri= 
                                 {returnUrl}", forceLoad: true);
        }
   </NotAuthorized>`

This retrieves the url of the last page you were trying to access, the Fetchdata page, and then navigate to the Login Razor page from which a password challenge is performed, that is the user is redirected to okta's login page to authenticate.

After the user has authenticated he's redirected to the Fetchdata page.

Last but not least, add the following at the top of the Fetchdata page:
`@page "/authorization-code/fetchdata"`

Note that the Fetchdata component has already have a @page directive, and this one is the second. Multiple route templates are legitimate in Blazor... But why do I add it ? This is because the return url passed from okta to our app is `"/authorization-code/fetchdata"`, and not "/fetchdata", as we might have expected, as the returnUrl we extracted from the navigation manager is "fetchdata". I'm not sure I understand the role of "/authorization-code/", and why it is enforced on us. I really did not have the time to investigate. However, this url segment is required by okta, and any attempt to do without it has failed, both in my code and in the dashboard in okta web site. I can get rid of this url segment in code, but this is not an issue. I just want to know why we need to provide it, so I can deal with it better. If you happen to learn more about it, please report it here, as I cannot spend more time investigating...

Incidentally, the solution provided in the article is by no mean complete; I dare say, rather partial.

Good luck...

Comment: Wow Thank you so much.  There's a lot here to review. I probably will have questions.  I have a lot going on as well today.  But, I will get back to you as soon as I can.  Again, thanks!!!

Comment: Update: The Authentication changes that you outline below worked.  Thank You, Thank You, Thank You.  Right off the bat, it redirected me to my okta log in page.  However, I was having problems with the redirect back to the Home Page. To resolve I had to add "/oauth2/default" at the end of my Issuer Url. You didn't have that.  The original article did. I am going to try the Authorization code you suggested in the update.  Good stuff

Comment: No, I didn't have it. I've used the url in the original article, but it didn't work, so I tried the url I got in their dashboard, and it worked perfectly fine. I've now tried it with "/oauth2/default" , and it works too. I'll update my answer to reflect this, so others won't fail here. If you happen to learn what is the role of "/authorization-code/callback", please report it here. @Richard, would you mind marking it as the answer if it solved your problem, so others know it was useful.

Comment: Update 2: I got the Authorization code working as well.  So, Thank you.  I did as you requested.  I am also going to update the original post from above to reference this answer so others can set this up properly.  Thanks again for all of your help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Is there a way to do away with the login/logout pages? I want to go to my URL and auto jump to Okta and attempt SSO. Either I'll be automatically authenticated as I'll be on my enterprise integrated machine or I'll login using Okta's UI. I'll come back authorized and proceed to main page (or return URL). The users of my application do not want to see a Login page that I made myself and I cannot figure out how to handle return URL