# Blazor Server Side with Okta will not start - Okta Dev Forums have no answer after a week

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, openid-connect, blazor, okta

I am trying to integrate my Blazor app with Okta, which I previously had done using the React SPA framework and their documentation. As I've tried to do this, I've run into an issue both within my own application and the default steps I have found here: [Okta blazer setup guide](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/10/16/csharp-blazor-authentication)
Likewise, the code that I have written can be found in this github repo: 
[Blazor Okta App](https://github.com/CSOleson/Okta-Blazor-Test)
Here is my error, which I believe is an issue with OIDC:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/10/16/csharp-blazor-authentication)
>         An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
>   System.InvalidOperationException: Provide Authority, MetadataAddress, Configuration, or ConfigurationManager to OpenIdConnectOptions
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectOptions.Validate()
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationOptions.Validate(String scheme)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass4_0`2.<AddSchemeHelper>b__1(TOptions o)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ValidateOptions`1.Validate(String name, TOptions options)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsFactory`1.Create(String name)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsMonitor`1.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.b__0()
>      at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
>      at System.Lazy`1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor)
>      at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
>      at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsCache`1.GetOrAdd(String name, Func`1 createOptions)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsMonitor`1.Get(String name)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.InitializeAsync(AuthenticationScheme scheme, HttpContext context)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandlerProvider.GetHandlerAsync(HttpContext context, String authenticationScheme)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

The steps I took to get here were:

1. Create new template from this command: `dotnet new blazorserver -o OktaBlazorAspNetCoreServerSide`
2. run template via `dotnet run` to make sure the template works (success)
3. Add the okta SDK via cli: `dotnet add package Okta.Sdk --version 1.4.0`
4. Add OIDC via cli: `dotnet add package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect --version 3.0.0`
5. Add a new okta app (web) [New web app settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZXMv.png)
6. Add my okta instance into my appsettings.json file (this is ok to share since it is just a throwaway apps key/secret):

   "Okta": {
       "ClientId": "0oa3p68xyxNszKiXt357",
       "ClientSecret": "ghZtcNIaKK6AFlEuPmXox2miaOQT2PErGqbkLXne",
       "OktaDomain": "https://dev-715227.okta.com/oauth2/default"
     }
7. Update the startup.cs file to include the necessary usings, configureservices, and authorization:

> ```
> using System;
> using System.Collections.Generic;
> using System.Linq;
> using System.Threading.Tasks;
> using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
> using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
> using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
> using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
> using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
> using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
> using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
> using OktaBlazorAspNetCoreServerSide.Data;
> using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
> using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
> using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging;
> ```

```
namespace OktaBlazorAspNetCoreServerSide
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddServerSideBlazor();
            services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();

            services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
            {
                sharedOptions.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                sharedOptions.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                sharedOptions.DefaultSignOutScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
            {
                options.ClientId = Configuration["Okta:ClientId"];
                options.ClientSecret = Configuration["Okta:ClientSecret"];
                options.CallbackPath = "/authorization-code/callback";
                options.Authority = Configuration["Okta:Issuer"];
                options.ResponseType = "code";
                options.SaveTokens = true;
                options.Scope.Add("openid");
                options.Scope.Add("profile");
                options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer = false;
                options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "name";
            })
            .AddCookie();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();
            //Add Auth to app
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                //Add MapControllers to app
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
                endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

8. Add the login controller:

```
        using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
        using System.Threading.Tasks;

      namespace BlazorServerWithOkta.Controllers
    {


     public class LoginController : Controller
             {
                 [HttpGet("Login")]
            public IActionResult Login([FromQuery]string returnUrl)
            {
                if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                     return LocalRedirect(returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/"));
                }
     return Challenge();
            }

            [HttpGet("Logout")]
            public async Task<IActionResult> Logout([FromQuery]string returnUrl)
            {
                if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    return LocalRedirect(returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/"));
                }

                await HttpContext.SignOutAsync();

                return LocalRedirect(returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/"));
            }

            [HttpPost("Logout")]
            [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
            public IActionResult PostLogout([FromQuery]string returnUrl)
            {
                returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");
                returnUrl = Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) ? returnUrl : Url.Content("~/");

                if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    HttpContext.SignOutAsync();
                }

                return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
            }

        }
    }
```

9. Add login razor component:

   Hello, @context.User.Identity.Name!
           Logout
       
       
           Log in

   10. Add the component to MainLayout:

   ````
       <LoginDisplay />
       <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/" target="_blank">About</a>
   </div>```


   11. Replace the App.razor code with Okta's code: 

   ```<CascadingValue Name="AccessToken" Value="AccessToken">
       <CascadingAuthenticationState>
           <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
               <Found Context="routeData">
                   <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
               </Found>
               <NotFound>
                   <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                       <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
                   </LayoutView>
               </NotFound>
           </Router>
       </CascadingAuthenticationState>
   </CascadingValue>
   @code{
       [Parameter] public string AccessToken { get; set; }
   }```


   12. Attempt to run app and see error: 
   > Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
     An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
   System.InvalidOperationException: Provide Authority, MetadataAddress, Configuration, or ConfigurationManager to OpenIdConnectOptions
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectOptions.Validate()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationOptions.Validate(String scheme)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass4_0`2.<AddSchemeHelper>b__1(TOptions o)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ValidateOptions`1.Validate(String name, TOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsFactory`1.Create(String name)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsMonitor`1.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.<Get>b__0()
   at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
   at System.Lazy`1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor)
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsCache`1.GetOrAdd(String name, Func`1 createOptions)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsMonitor`1.Get(String name)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.InitializeAsync(AuthenticationScheme scheme, HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandlerProvider.GetHandlerAsync(HttpContext context, String authenticationScheme)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   ````

As far as I can tell, as previously stated, this appears to be an error with OIDC. I've tried to correct the issue by adding an authority in startup.cs (
                options.Authority = Configuration["Okta:Issuer"];) or following others who have had their error. I cannot seem to get this to work, and Okta has been completely silent on my issue when I've posted it in the Okta Dev forums. Can anyone guide me on this one? I am assuming this is my lack of knowledge surrounding ASP.NET and OIDC.

Comment: I did not read your question, but as it is redirecting to the article the sample of which I helped a user here to make running, I'd suggest to see my answer  here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59469127/6152891. There was also another question here about Okta I helped to solve. I just don't remember the url. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you, @enet! Unfortunately, the app will not even launch in its current state and after following their article, so I cannot even get to the point where your suggestion would be able to be implemented.