# Blazor (Server-Side) - Button onclick fails to NavigateTo while a link's href doesn't

Tags: c#, blazor-server-side

I trying to figure out OpenID + Okta + Blazor on this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59469127/481656. I made the `LoginDisplay.razor` as per the answer but it would render a simple hyperlink for Login:

```
<NotAuthorized>
   <a href="login?redirectUri=/">Log in</a>
</NotAuthorized>
```

It works and I get redirected to Okta but I needed a button, so I made the following changes to my `LoginDisplay.razor`:

```
@using Syncfusion.Blazor.Buttons
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
        Hello, @context.User.Identity.Name!&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        <SfButton OnClick="@((args) => NavigateToLogin())" CssClass="e-warning" IconCss="fad fa-sign-in fa-fw theme-da" IconPosition=@IconPosition.Left>Login</SfButton>
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>


@code {
    private void NavigateToLogin()
    {
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/login?redirectUri=/");
    }
}
```

But when I click this button, the site simply reports the NotFound message: Sorry, there's nothing at this address. How do I make my button work?